# What is the best way to solve a system of linear equations with infinite solutions?

Tags: c++, equation-solving

I want to solve a system of linear equations (SLE, Ax=b, where A consists out of 8 rows and columns) but this system will always have infinite solutions. Many people refer to Eigen, when it comes down to solving system of linear equations. 
However, as a result it would be great if I have some kind of "dependencies" between the variables, so that I just need to set the values of the free variables and get the results. E.g:

```
x1 = 5.234*x2 + 2.3232x3
x2 = 3.234 + 1.3*x3
x3 = free.
```

I looked in the Eigen documentation but they don't mention SLEs with infinite many solutions.
Is Eigen capable of doing this kindof calculation or is there a better 
library?

Regards

EDIT:

The system could look like

```
0.4*f1+0.0*f2+0.6*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.4*f2+0.0*f3+0.6*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.3*f5+0.0*f6+0.7*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.5*f7+0.5*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
0.0*f1+0.0*f2+0.0*f3+0.0*f4+0.0*f5+0.0*f6+0.0*f7+0.0*f8= fx
```

Where the number of rows with coefficients of only zero may vary and fx is an arbitrary value. The trivial solution f1=f2=f3=f4=f5=f6=F7=f8=fx=0 cannot be used. I could repeat rows in order to get rid of the rows with empty coefficients.

Comment: If the rank of the matrix is too low, Eigen fails AFAIK. Then your subsequent question is out of scope for SO.

Comment: Maybe look at Armadillo library

Comment: I'm probably missing something here. If you have too many variables and too few equations, you have infinite solutions, but _for linear equations_ those will form a hyperplane. By picking values for free variables, you take the intersection of that hyperplane with another (axis-aligned) hyperplane. By picking enough free variables, you are left with a single point which is your single solution..

Comment: Also, while you mention an 8x8 matrix, your example is 3x2. That's why you have a free variable. If you need just _a_ solution, substitute x3=0. That's usually the easiest solution.

Comment: You mean, that I start picking values for free variables, then check if I can fulfill one equation and continue? Let's say  I choose an arbitrary value for fx and one for f8. The I could already solve equation 5 with f4*0.3+0.7*f8 = fx. The I continue with an abritrary value for f7 and so forth?

Comment: If there is an infinite number of solutions, you need 1. to get one solution (e.g. with pseudo-inverse) and 2. to get a basis of Ker A. All the solutions are provided by the first solution + linear function of the basis

Answer (score 3):

If `x1` and `x2` are two solutions, then `A(x1 - x2) = 0`, i.e. the vector `x1 -x2` owns to the null-space of `A` (the kernel `Ker A`).

Therefore, if `x0` is a particular solution and if the `v[i]` form a basis of `Ker A`, then the set of all solutions is provided by:

```
x = x0 + sum_i a[i] v[i], where a[i] are any real numbers
```

In Eigen, some decompositions are rank-revealing, e.g. `FullPivLU`.

According to Eigen site, you can get a basis of the kernel with for example:

```
Matrix3f A;
.......
FullPivL<Matrix3f> lu_decomp(A);
auto K = lu_decomp.kernel();
```

As `FullPivLU` has a solver, you should get one particular solution with:

```
lu_decomp.solve (...);
```